# ¿Que significa HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory

Comment: Si no explicas el escenario en la que te aparece el texto, va a ser complicado ayudarte. Veo que has completado el [tour], deberías ya conocer cómo hacer una pregunta y por qué es importante crear un [mcve]